# Hover zoom doesnt work on second page of datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I displayed img thumbnail on last column of databale

```
$.each(data,function(i,d){
    d['index']=i+1; 
    url = url
    d["ad_image"] = '<a href="#" ><img src="'+url+'" class="img-zoom" /></a>'
})  
table = $('#datatable4').dataTable({
    'paging':   true,  
    'ordering': true,  
    'info':     true,  
    "destroy": true,
    "aaData" : data,
    aoColumns: [
      { mData: 'index' },
      { mData: 'ad_title' },
      { mData: 'ad_details' },
      { mData: 'ad_image' },
    ]
});
```

> img-zoom class css :

```
.img-zoom {
width: 310px;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.transition {
-webkit-transform: scale(2); 
-moz-transform: scale(2);
-o-transform: scale(2);
transform: scale(2);
}
```

But when I go to second page zoom image is not working...
on the first page its working...
how can I use fndrawcallback here?? or is there any other option??

```
$('.img-zoom').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('transition');

}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('transition');
});
```

Comment: Where is the code that is adding the `.transition` class in JQuery?

Comment: no.. its in another file.. i.e. app.css

Comment: Based on your question, there is no JQuery adding the `.transition` class on hover and the `:hover` selector is missing from your CSS code. I don't see where any hover effect is generated from this code.

Comment: its workin on first page of datatable.... it means transition is woking...

Comment: I'm not saying it's not working. I'm saying the code you have given isn't all of the code. Where in the code that you have given does a hover effect get triggered?

Comment: Now I update the que...

Comment: You have an error in that hover code. The second `});` at the end is not needed. Is this hover function nested in another function in any way?

Comment: }) is of ready function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a delegated event handler - the content of page #2 is not available when the code is executed, thats why the zoom not is working on page #2 :

```js
$('#datatable4').on('mouseenter', '.img-zoom', function() {
    $(this).addClass('transition')
})
$('#datatable4').on('mouseleave', '.img-zoom', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('transition')
})
```

**Updated**. The `hover` pseudo event name cannot be used as I suggested, doing the same thing as `hover()`. My bad. Use the above solution instead, here is a demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/wa0oykv7/** find for example `seq #57` (the last row) and hover the mouse over first column which has the class `.img-zoom`.

Comment: still its not working.... when I replace above code it also not working on first page of datatable

Comment: @AkshayAmbekar, you are right - have updated the answer. Hopefully this works better for you; I apologize for the wrong code example!

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Its working perfectly :) @davidkonrad